# How to resolve: DLL load failed: The file tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal could not be found

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-3.7

I upgraded TensorFlow to have version 2.0.0 (or up) on Windows 10. But when I import TensorFlow on Jupyter notebook I get the following error.

```
ImportError   Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
.


ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\phess\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

There are plenty of other posts related to this topic, but none of them were helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: pip install tensorflow==2.